# Invalid path on nuget restore step

Tags: tfs, nuget, tfsbuild

I have TFS service on premise. I am trying to setup build and stuck on nuget restore step.
I have pass target solution to settings:

```
Path to solution or packages.config: $/MyProject/MySolution.sln
```

On log, nuget fails due to invalid directory

```
NuGet.exe restore -NonInteractive D:\TFS\agent01\_work\63\s -ConfigFile \\SomePath\Nuget.config -NoCache -Verbosity Detailed
```

As you can see, invalid target is passed to nuget.
It should be

```
D:\TFS\agent01\_work\63\s\$\MyProject\MySolution.sln
```

But is

```
D:\TFS\agent01\_work\63\s
```

In other projects works as expected. What could be wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Do you have it declared as a build step? It looks like you somewhere put a remote path where it can't be resolved on the agent. I have a very similar setup running and it works with the NuGet-Installer build step:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that, the problem was `Get Source` step.
In `Server path` variable I had path to solution  itself instead of( sln file) of folder to solution.